# Request to server API using Java and JSON

Tags: java, json, api, request, response

I have documentation of server API with several methods. The problem is that I have never used API to work with server. What I can do to do it more easy?

### **Part of API documentation:**

**Method "Login":**

POST http://api.example.com/login-ajax

**Parameters:**

- email
- password

**Response:**

```
{
    "success":true,
    "currentUser":222,
    "userData":{
        "displayName":"User",
        "displayAvatarId":"asjhdsasduh",
        "email":"qwerty@gmail.com",
        "isEmailConfirmed":"0",
        "sex":"m"
    }
}
```

The response is JSON object, but I don't know how to send request to get this response.

Help me please.

### UPGRADE

I tried to use Jsoup:

```
Connection.Response res = Jsoup.connect("http://api.example.com/login-ajax")
                .data("email", "mail@gmail.com", "password", "pass")
                .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                .header("Accept", "application/json")
                .header("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest")
                .header("X-App-Api", "1.0")
                .header("X-App", "iOS")
                .ignoreContentType(true)
                .execute();
        Document document = Jsoup.parse(res.parse().outerHtml());
        System.out.println(document.text());
```

The response is:

```
{"success":false,"exception":"Exception_User","message":"\u041c\u044b \u043d\u0435 \u043d\u0430\u0448\u043b\u0438 \u0432 \u0431\u0430\u0437\u0435 \u0442\u0430\u043a\u043e\u0435 \u0441\u043e\u0447\u0435\u0442\u0430\u043d\u0438\u0435 \u044d\u043b. \u043f\u043e\u0447\u0442\u044b \u0438 \u043f\u0430\u0440\u043e\u043b\u044f. \u041f\u043e\u0436\u0430\u043b\u0443\u0439\u0441\u0442\u0430, \u043f\u043e\u043f\u0440\u043e\u0431\u0443\u0439\u0442\u0435 \u0435\u0449\u0435 \u0440\u0430\u0437."}
```

### UPGRADE 2

I also tried to use this one:

```
System.out.println(getJSON("http://api.example.com/login-ajax"));

public static String getJSON(String url) {
        try {
            URL u = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
            c.setRequestMethod("POST");
            c.setRequestProperty("email", "mail@gmail.com");
            c.setRequestProperty("password", "pass");
            c.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            c.setRequestProperty("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
            c.setRequestProperty("X-App-Api", "1.0");
            c.setRequestProperty("X-App", "iOS");
            c.setUseCaches(false);
            c.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
            c.setConnectTimeout(1000);
            c.setReadTimeout(1000);
            c.connect();
            int status = c.getResponseCode();

            switch (status) {
                case 200:
                    System.out.println("200");
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(c.getInputStream()));
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    String line;
                    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                    br.close();
                    return sb.toString();
                case 201:
                    System.out.println("201");
                    br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(c.getInputStream()));
                    sb = new StringBuilder();
                    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                    br.close();
                    return sb.toString();
            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            System.out.println("MalformedURLException");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("IOException");
        }
        return null;
    }
```

And the response is:

```
{"success":false,"exception":"Exception_Validation","message":"\u041d\u0435\u043f\u0440\u0430\u0432\u0438\u043b\u044c\u043d\u044b\u0439 e-mail","errors":{"email":["\u041f\u043e\u0436\u0430\u043b\u0443\u0439\u0441\u0442\u0430, \u0432\u0432\u0435\u0434\u0438\u0442\u0435 e-mail."],"password":["\u0412\u0432\u0435\u0434\u0438\u0442\u0435 \u043f\u0430\u0440\u043e\u043b\u044c"]}}
```

Comment: Do you not know what a request parameter is? Url-endoded form params?

Comment: I know what is it, but I don't know how to use them.

Comment: Read up on HTTP, then find and use a Java HTTP client.

Comment: I try to use Jsoup to make post request, but I got bad response.

Comment: Show us what you attempted with all the details.

Comment: What you are doing seems fine. What does the error message say. I don't know the language (Russian?).

Comment: Yes the main problem is that it's russian symbols but they look like code: \u041d\u0435\u043f.

Comment: That's just unicode, not a big deal. You can convert them to a String with some utility.

Comment: Can I do this inside code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I haven't used Jsoup so far I can't give detailed information on how to use it, but I had to work with Restlet and therefore created my own JSON messages (either via org.json.JSONObject or via plain String). A post-example using Restlet would look something like this:

```
try
{
    // create a Restlet client
    ClientResource cr = new ClienResource("http://api.example.com/login-ajax");
    // create the JSON message
    JSONObject message = new JSONObject();
    message.put("email", "mail@gmail.com");
    message.put("password", "pass");
    // use HTTP POST method to send the JSON message
    cr.post(message, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

    // receive the answer - error checks omitted!
    Response response = cr.getResponse();
    JsonRepresentation jsonRep = new JsonRepresentation(response.getEntity());

    // process the JSON response
    JSONObject json = jsonRep.getJsonObject();
    System.out.println("success: "+json.get("success"));
    System.out.println("current user: "+json.get("currentUser"));

    // extract the user data
    JSONObject userData = (JSONObject)json.get("userData");
    System.out.println("display name: "+userData.get("displayName"));
    System.out.println("display avatar Id: "+userData.get("displayAvatarId"));
    System.out.println("email: "+userData.get("email"));
    System.out.println("is email confirmed: "+userData.get("isEmailConfirmed"));
    System.out.println("sex: "+userData.get("sex"));
}
catch (ResourceException | JSONException ex)
{
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

HTH

Comment: I load Restlet, but how I can import Restlet into my project?

Answer (score 0):

Consider to use an [Apache HTTP Client](http://hc.apache.org/) to create a connection to your HTTP server.
Its a general-purpose library for working with HTTP requests. There are plenty resources that illustrate the usage of HTTP client, [Here is an example](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/restful-java-client-with-apache-httpclient/)

I admit, I've never used JSoup so I can't really comment on your example.

Hope this helps,
Mark